# Is there a way to test my site for js errors (specifically in china)

Tags: javascript, web, great-firewall-of-china

Chinese users of my site are reporting issues, i'm thinking that some js files must be getting blocked. does anyone have a good way for me (outside china) to debug the issue.

Comment: https://www.dotcom-tools.com/website-speed-test.aspx or other sites from https://geekflare.com/test-website-load-time-from-china/ might work (they only work sporadically on my test), you probably could setup VPN on a VPS located in mainland China https://www.alibabacloud.com/global-locations though I'm not sure if those VPS are also covered by the firewall (it supposed to be, because otherwise it's an easy VPN to bypass the firewall, but maybe it's not that the approach taken by the Chinese govt)